# Loading text file from zip archive with minizip/zlib, garbage characters at end of file

Tags: c++, c, zlib, zip

I am trying to load shader source from inside a zip file, which is a plain text file created with notepad. loading code is as follows (error checking code removed from the below snippet):

```
std::string retrievestringfromarchive(std::string filename)
{
//data is the zip resource attached elsewhere
unz_file_info info;
Uint8* rwh;

unzLocateFile(data, filename.c_str(), NULL);
unzOpenCurrentFile(data);
unzGetCurrentFileInfo(data, &info, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0)
rwh = (Uint8*)malloc(info.uncompressed_size);
unzReadCurrentFile( data, rwh, info.uncompressed_size );

//garbage at end of file
const char* rwh1 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(rwh);
std::stringstream tempstream(rwh1);
std::string tempstring = tempstream.str();
free(rwh);
return tempstring;
}
```

The output of the string returned is as follows:

```
//FRAGMENT SHADER    
#version 120    

//in from vertex shader    
varying vec2 f_texcoord;    
varying vec4 f_color;

uniform sampler2D mytexture;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(mytexture, f_texcoord) * f_color;
}
//endfile««««««««îþîþ
```

Notes:

- i checked the info struct, both compressed and uncompressed size matches with information from 7zip
- the buffer "rwh" itself has the garbage characters at the end, when inspected with gdb
- I am on Win7 64bit, using codeblocks and TDM-GCC-32 4.8.1 to compile
- the "//endfile" comment neatly avoids gl shader compile issue, but that has gotta go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> rwh = (Uint8*)malloc(info.uncompressed_size);
> unzReadCurrentFile( data, rwh, info.uncompressed_size );
> ```

I highly doubt that `unzReadCurrentFile` adds a `0` terminator in the buffer - there would be no space anyway - and your are using the pointer as a `0`-terminated string.

In case it really makes sense to interpret the buffer as a string, you can do it like so:

```
std::string tempstring(rwh1, info.uncompressed_size);
```

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. I took out the stringstream too. I had looked at an example that used a stringstream in between, but thats not necessary apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The decompressor gives you a block of decompressed data – but it doesn't know the data is a plain text and that you are planning to use it as a C-language string. So it doesn't append a terminating NUL (zero) character at the end. Thats all. Simply copy **a given number of characters** and do not assume the data block is zero-terminated.